# Issue for receipt validation in Android in react-native-iap

Tags: android, react-native, google-apis-explorer, react-native-iap

**Version of react-native-iap**
5.2.11

**Version of react-native**
0.63.4

**Platforms you faced the error (IOS or Android or both?)**
Android

**Tested environment (Emulator? Real Device?)**
Real device

```
await RNIap.validateReceiptAndroid(
purchases.packageNameAndroid,
purchases.productId,
purchases.purchaseToken,
token,
true,
)
.then((res) => {
debugLog(res);
})
.catch((error) => {
debugLog('error', error);
});
```

> error Error at index.js:855 at step (index.js:32) at Object.next
> (index.js:13) at fulfilled (index.js:4) at tryCallOne (core.js:37) at
> core.js:123 at JSTimers.js:274 at _callTimer (JSTimers.js:130) at
> _callImmediatesPass (JSTimers.js:181) at MessageQueue.callImmediates [as _immediatesCallback] (JSTimers.js:441)

'also this link gives me error'
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions/get?apix_params=%7B%22packageName%22%3A%22com.app.jukejam%22%2C%22subscriptionId%22%3A%22venueautorenew%22%2C%22token%22%3A%22knlhipkgflcainjemoinkidg.AO-J1OxZrCRJaqBnS1cs_vlf6ZIlJ4TiCmCej0o3hc0E7pMDW2XCsqeI7HG88KwZZuxRnz7AxKfJdyj1tdSfvi2o64SRAyQ8lw%22%2C%22access_token%22%3A%22ya29.A0AfH6SMDbiOwyKcY4BWi1b6OkJdl8Ft-m6PShLUtbqw-JeB01KFYCRFmFaX07_QKsbwjaqvlpVNwtNzWygfJH-po4dbH-w7VTIrCj3q0ajD_pu8DSrCwqbM871Jc2UB9KgDnANBeS8OGsFiDv5MrZuL7tx8my%22%7D

> "error": { "code": 403, "message": "The project id used to call the
> Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play
> Developer Console.", "errors": [   {
> "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.",
> "domain": "androidpublisher",
> "reason": "projectNotLinked"   } ]

Comment: Did you found any solution for this issue? if yes, please leave a comment that'll be helpful for us. Since i got stuck in this for more than 2 weeks.

Comment: @Pans check this for answer https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap/issues/1262